# FB iframe like button is permitted by TOS?

Tags: javascript, php, facebook-like

I have seen on several sites that they embed the like button as an iframe not the standard fb-like tag that Facebook recommends. It looks like this:

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=PUT_URL_HERE&amp;width&amp;layout=standard&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=true&amp;share=true&amp;height=80" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Is this practice permitted by Facebook or the owners of the sites risk something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the old embed code with the iframe. Should still work, i guess, but is definitely not recommended to use. Always use the code from the Like Button Plugin page. The iframe solution MAY stop working sooner or later, but it´s definitely not "against the TOS" ;)

Comment: The official generator https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button still offers the iframe code, so I don’t think this is deprecated in any way.